# Spring MVC and Spring Task Configuration Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC Application. I am trying to configure @async method in a class but it is failing when I put

```
<task:executor id="taskExecutorPool" pool-size="10"/>
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutorPool"/>
```

**Spring Configuration**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <task:executor id="taskExecutorPool" pool-size="10"/>
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutorPool"/>
```

**Class**

```
@Component
public class RestClient {

    @Async
    public <T> T asyncGet(String restPath, Map<String, ?> params, Class<T> cls){
        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(getEBizCareRestURL(restPath));
        for(String key : params.keySet()){
            uriBuilder.queryParam(key, params.get(key));
        }
        return restTemplate.getForEntity(uriBuilder.build().toUri(), cls).getBody();
    }
}
```

**Maven Dependencies**

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <jdk.version>1.6.0_29</jdk.version>
        <jetty.version>8.1.8.v20121106</jetty.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <loggingFramework.version>1.0</loggingFramework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Exception:-**

```
<Jul 15, 2014 12:17:30 AM CDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/Ordered.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/Ordered
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/Ordered
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.Ordered
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: The error is surprising : classloader does not find `org.springframework.core.Ordered` when it exists in `spring-core` artifact declared in you pom ... Could there be another version of spring library somewhere in your web server (seems to be `weblogic`), or brought by another part of your application ?

Comment: I thought the same but again after reading your comment I validated again in class path but didn't found any other version of spring in class path.